# Adding a @HandleBeforeSave method to my @RepositoryEventHandler class removes the underlying @Entiry from my REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

**Problem**

I am using `spring` and in the process I have added a `@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)` for updates (PUT) when I go to modify a user.

I would like to be able to set who is making the edits to the `User`.

I created a `@HandleBeforeCreate` which works fine for HTTP POST's but as soon as I add the `@HandleBeforeSave` the `User` REST API is no longer available.  I do not see a `stack trace` being created.

**Question**

Am I missing something with regards to creating the `@HandleBeforeSave`

**@RepositoryEventHandler**

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
public class SpringDataRestEventHandler {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpringDataRestEventHandler(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void applyUserInformationUsingSecurityContext(User user) throws  {


        String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        User manager = this.userRepository.findByUserName(name);

        if (!manager.hasRole("ROLE_MANAGER")) {
            throw new Exception("No manager found for user on applyUserInformationUsingSecurityContext.");
        }
        user.setManager(name);

    }

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void applyManagerFromSecurityContext(User user)  {

        System.out.println("calling before save");
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private SpringDataJpaUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(MCBPasswordEncoder.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/built/**", "/main.css").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
      .httpBasic()
        .and()
      .csrf().disable()  // TODO enable for production
      .logout()
              .invalidateHttpSession(true)
              .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
  }

}
```

Comment: Minor: the method hasRole doesn't need its argument to have the ROLE_ prefix. 
Check@ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146110/when-should-i-prefix-role-with-spring-security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was actually related to the 2 repositories I created for the `User` @Entity.  I was getting weird results where the API would show up (with the one repo) and disappear with the other repo.

I have since fixed this by

- Use only one repo instead of two Extend Repository instead that
  JPARepository
- Copy and paste methods that i needed from PagingAndSortingRepository.
- Added   @PreAuthorize accordingly to specific methods, not to
  the class.  This was the initial problem as I split it out when I wanted to manipulate the repo outside of the REST api.