# When should I prefix ROLE_ with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In Spring Security, when is it appropriate to add the `"ROLE_"` prefix?  In examples using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`, it does. But in this example, it doesn't:

```
http
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

What about the following?

```
SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
final Properties users = new Properties();
users.put("joe","secret,ADMIN,enabled");            <-- here
InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
```

and

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));         <-- here
AnonymousAuthenticationToken anonymousAuthenticationToken = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("test", manager.loadUserByUsername("joe"), grantedAuthorities);
        securityContext.setAuthentication(anonymousAuthenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
```

Are there any specific rules of the usage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Automatic `ROLE_` prefixing

As [Spring Security 3.x to 4.x migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing) states:

> Spring Security 4 automatically prefixes **any role** with `ROLE_`. The
>   changes were made as part of [SEC-2758](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2984)

With that being said, the `ROLE_` prefix in the following annotation is redundant:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```

Since you're calling `hasRole` method, the fact that you're passing a **role** is implied. Same is true for the following expression:

```
antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

But for the:

```
new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

Since this is an authority, not a role, you should add the `ROLE_` prefix (If your intent is to create a role!). Same is true for calling `public InMemoryUserDetailsManager(Properties users)` constructor, since it's using an authority [internally](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/InMemoryUserDetailsManager.java#L64).

Comment: Thanks for your info. That clarify my confusion in regarding of the role prefix usage,

Comment: A follow-up question, if putting the last two portion code together, the role data has not any effect in the user properties, right? The grantAuthorities override any role setup in the user.

Comment: Honestly I did not fully understand your question!

Comment: A user role is set in users.put("joe","secret,ADMIN,enabled");* And late grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")); and  new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("test", manager.loadUserByUsername("joe"), grantedAuthorities); My question is that whether it is correct to say I can put any role on the line * or not in this situation.

Comment: I don't know, tbh.