# Cannot configure spring boot security - always 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So i have to configure spring security and I believe I missing something because it is giving me a 403 - Forbidden.
Any spring expert help would be highly appreciated!

I made it a little more simple to focus on the solution, the original code is more complex but the error is still the same.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class JWTSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf()
                        .disable()
                    .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(WebSecurityConfig::handleException)
                        .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/images/**")
                        .hasAnyRole("MY_USER", "MY_ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

The filter class is simple and does little:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                        .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                "John Doe",
                                null,
                                List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("MY_USER")))
                        );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            }

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

After I call the REST endpoint:

```
GET http://localhost:8083/images/parcels/parcel1/data
```

It always ends up with the spring's default 403 response. I don't see what am I missing. Any help would be great.

Comment: How do you provide your username and password?

Comment: @tashkhisi It is going to be a jwt token authorizator so I don't need the password. I am using a cert to verify the token. That's why I didn't add the credentials in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken's constructor. Having the same issue if I change the 'null' to anything else.

Comment: @Kulfy ```/images/parcels/{parcelId}/data```. The token comes with the ```Authorization``` header as a Bearer. But it is working and not the part of the problem. It is the same issue if i do not use any token or any parameter in the url. Always get a 403 even if i make the function that simple like the one I wrote.

Comment: @Kulfy intellij idea .http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new SimpleGrantedAuthority("MY_USER")` is an authority not role.

You should use `hasAnyAuthority("MY_USER", "MY_ADMIN")` instead of `hasAnyRole("MY_USER", "MY_ADMIN")`

edit: or you can use role prefix

```
private String defaultRolePrefix = "ROLE_";
```

--

```
 new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_MY_USER")
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working for me in this way: have to add the prefix in ```new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_MY_USER"))```. In this way i can use the ```hasAnyAuthority(String... auths)``` and ```hasAnyRole(String... roles)``` methods

Comment: Further reading in more depth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146110/when-should-i-prefix-role-with-spring-security